# Crash with "Padding is invalid and cannot be removed" when the CryptoStream closes

Tags: c#, encryption, windows-mobile

**tl;dr** Encrypting and Decrypting work fine and correct. I checked everything. The problem appears when I don't read the entire content from the `CryptoStream`. I use the `RijndaelManaged` class and the app is for Windows Mobile 6.

This app works with XMLs and it must encrypt everything written to disk. After it gets the XML (in memory), it encrypts the content directly into a file. Later, the app has to combine all these small XMLs into a big one, but in the meantime we may need some info from the XML. To optimize memory usage, I did not load the entire XML in memory, I used an `XmlReader` that reads from a `CryptoStream` only what it needs. But this crashes with *"Padding is invalid and cannot be removed"*.

For example, this works perfectly:

```
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(ResponsePath, FileMode.Open))
using (var crpytoStream = new CryptoStream(fileStream, key.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
using (var reader = StreamReader.Create(crpytoStream, settings))
{
    reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

And this not:

```
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(ResponsePath, FileMode.Open))
using (var crpytoStream = new CryptoStream(fileStream, key.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
using (var reader = StreamReader.Create(crpytoStream, settings))
{
    var buffer = new char[1024];
    reader.ReadBlock(buffer , 0, 1024);
}
```

I have a solution, but it looks like a terrible hack and it's not good for gigantic XMLs. I appreciate if you know a cleaner solution.

Edit:
I tested reading a different number of bytes from the stream.

- If I start from 0 and read 1, 2, 3, ... or 1024 bytes, it will crash when I close the stream.
- If I start from 0 and read 1025, 1026, 1027, ... or 2048 bytes, it will not crash when I close the stream.
- If I start from 0 and read 2049, 2050, ... or 4096 bytes, it will crash
  when I close the stream.
- If I start from 0 and read 4097 bytes, it will not crash when I close the stream.
- If I start from 0 and read 8192 bytes, it will crash
  when I close the stream.

IV is loaded before reading.

Comment: Those are not on block boundaries, 0 -> 1023 is on block boundaries. A block boundry is a multiple of (for AES) 16-bytes. Indexes start at 0.

Comment: AES is a block based encryption algorithm, it process one block at a time. So there is no problem decryption starting at other than the beginning as long as the starting point is on a block boundary that was used during encryption and the length is a multiple of the block size. For CBC mode the prior block is xor'ed with the data prior to encryption and on decryption must be again xor'ed with the decrypted data. See [[CBC mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_Block_Chaining_.28CBC.29).

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you want to say. I always read from 0, the first block being IV, from the `CryptoStream`. I'm not trying to start in the middle. 

The crash appears based on how much I read. 1 -> 1024 means this: if I read 1 byte (or 2, 3, ... until 1024 inclusive), then I close the stream, I get a crash. If I read 1025 bytes (or 1026, 1027,... until 2048), then no crash.

Comment: UPDATED: If you do not read the last block you must specify **no padding** as a decryption option, padding is only on the last block. See point (4) in my answer and [PKCS#7 padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS7). You must always read an **exact multiple of the block size**. If you are using CBC mode and do not start reading at the first block you must supply the previous block as the IV, see the first note in my answer. The answer does work if you get the blocks, IV and padding options right.

Comment: Ok, will check this. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to create another stream to read to the end. After I get all the data I need from the XML, I create a `StreamReader` and read all the content. This is obviously bad if the XML is gigantic.

```
using (var workaroundStream = new StreamReader(crpytoStream))
{
    var workaroundBuffer = new char[1024];
    while (workaroundStream.ReadBlock(workaroundBuffer, 0, 1024) != 0)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question and it is possible other than reading the entire encrypted data.

Comment: @zaph Really? I just answered my question with a solution that works and solves my problem, albeit in a bad way, and you are telling me it doesn't answer my question?

Comment: It is the "albeit in a bad way" part where there is a solution that is not bad. It would seem the question, if it really is a question given there is an implied answer in it, is about avoiding reading and decryption the entire file.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to read and decrypt from the middle of the encrypted data.

1. Start the read on a block boundary, 16-bytes for AES.
2. Stop reading on any block bounbdry.
3. Read a multiple of the block size.
4. Decrypt with no padding.

Notes:

- If the mode is CBC read one block prior and use the that as the IV.
- if reading to the end decrypt with padding.

AES is a block based encryption algorithm, it process one block at a time. So there is no problem decryption starting at other than the beginning as long as the starting point is on a block boundary that was used during encryption and the length is a multiple of the block size.

For CBC mode the prior block is xor'ed with the data prior to encryption and on decryption must be again xor'ed with the decrypted data. See [CBC mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_Block_Chaining_.28CBC.29).

See [PKCS#7 padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS7).